# $\vec{a} \times \vec{b} = \vec{c} \times \vec{d}$ . what can you say about the direction of $\vec{b} \times \vec{c}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

[image: question]

I know that $\vec{a} \times \vec{b}$ and $\vec{c} \times \vec{d}$ are perpendicular therefore the dot product would equal $0$.

Comment: You were told $\vec{a} \times \vec{b} = \vec{c} \times \vec{d}$.  Why would you think $\vec{a} \times \vec{b} $ and $\vec{c} \times \vec{d}$ would be perpendicular?

Comment: And where does the dot product come into this anyway?

Comment: My bad I though about it and since  they are the same the dot product can't equal zero.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The fact that $\vec{a} \times \vec{b}$ = $\vec{c} \times \vec{d}$ means that $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ lie in the same plane as $\vec{c}$ and $\vec{d}$. What does this tell you about a relationship between $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\vec{b} \times \vec{c}$ is orthogonal to both $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$.  What other vector mentioned in the problem is orthogonal to both of these?

Comment: well (b X c) is also orthogonal to (c x d) which is orthogonal to c and d. Does this mean (B x c) is orthogonal to c and d?

Comment: Is even that first statement correct? There's already a comment about that attached to your original question.

Comment: No, $c \times d$ is **not** orthogonal to $b \times c$, but it is orthogonal to $c$.  Now, why is it orthogonal to $b$?